# How can i update a textbox automatically when an even occurs?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, event-handling

ok so i have set up an event handler that triggers when a device connected to the computers serial port recieves a text message with this code:

```
   Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim rxString As String
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim newMsg As New SMSMessage

    RemoveHandler SMSPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

    Thread.Sleep(100)
    rxString = SMSPort.ReadExisting()
    rxString = TrimCRLF(rxString)

    index = NewSMSIndex(rxString)
    If index > -1 Then

        newMsg = ReadSMS(index)
        If newMsg.Index > -1 Then
            SMS.Clear()
            SMS.Add("Index: " & newMsg.Index & vbCrLf)
            SMS.Add("Phone Number: " & newMsg.PhoneNum & vbCrLf)
            SMS.Add(newMsg.RxOrTx & ": " & newMsg.MessageDateTime & vbCrLf)
            SMS.Add("Message: " & newMsg.MessageText)

        End If

    End If

    AddHandler SMSPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

End Sub
```

now this is a part of a class that is seperate to my GUI which is called MainWindow,

basically i cant figure out how to get a text box to update on the main windows with the lines i am writing to the list "SMS" in the code.

i spose what i want is:

when list changes, do task:

for each elem in list
textbox.appendtext(elem)
next
and then have the textbox display waht is written to it

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand the question, you can use [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx) to achieve that. Declare an event in class where you have SMS list, and raise the event whenever necessary :

```
Public Event SMSListChanged(ByVal someString As String)

Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    .....
    RaiseEvent SMSListChanged("Some message to display in MainWindow")
    .....
End Sub
```

Then in MainWindow handles SMSListChanged event :

```
Private WithEvents myOtherClass As New MyOtherClass
Private Sub DisplayMessage(ByVal message As String) Handles myOtherClass.SMSListChanged
    'TODO: update textbox with message string from parameter
End Sub
```

Advantage of this approach is to avoid your class from having additional responsibility which is updating GUI, hence can keep it comply with [Single Responsibility Priciple](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp) *at some level*.

Comment: thanks for the help i tried that and got an error "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types." and now i'm totally stumped

Comment: updated my answer, added `WithEvent` keyword before `myOtherClass`